# VB6: Speech to Text for certain phrases

Tags: com, vb6

I'm creating a chatbot on Visual Basic 6.

```
Private Sub GreetingSub()
    convo.Text = beconvo & nickname & ": " & Text.Text & vbNewLine & botname & 
   "Hello! How are you?" & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

This is a part of my code. So "nickname & ": " & Text.Text" is the user's name and what they wrote in the input box in the actual conversation box. botname & whatever is following that is what the bot replies.

I've tried Set objTextToSpeech = CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice"), however the program freezes and reads the entire conversation box, which is not what i want.

I need the chatbot to only say his reply out loud, not the user's.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If would help it you showed a concise snippet of code where you actually use the SAPI object.

Comment: Try adding the reference to the text to speech dll, if you don't see the reference you should validate it is well registered with Windows